# How to derive a procedure's HM type based on its implementation?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, hindley-milner

Given these two procedures (written in JavaScript) …

```
// comp :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
const comp = f=> g=> x=> f (g (x))

// comp2 :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> d)
const comp2 = comp (comp) (comp)
```

**My question is** how to derive `comp2`'s [Hindley-Milner Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) *without* referencing `comp`'s implementation

---

If we know `comp`'s implementation, it's easy … We can use the substitution model through the entire evaluation to arrive at the expanded expression …

```
comp (comp) (comp)
= (f => g => x => f (g (x))) (comp) (comp) 
= x => comp (comp (x))
= y => comp (comp (y)) 
= y => (f => g => x => f (g (x))) (comp (y))
... keep going until ...
= f=> g=> x=> y=> f (g (x) (y))
```

Ring-a-ding. The expanded evaluation matches `comp2`'s type. No one is impressed.

```
// comp2 :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> d)
const comp2 = f=> g=> x=> y=> f (g (x) (y))
```

But what if we only knew `comp`'s *type* and did **not** know its *implementation*? Instead of evaluating the code to determine the type, could I have performed some sort of substitutions/evaluation on `comp`'s type to end up with `comp2`'s type ?

---

Given only this, the problem becomes much harder … (at least for me)

```
// comp :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)

// comp2 :: ???
const comp2 = comp (comp) (comp)
```

There's gotta be a way, right ? Isn't this what [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) are all about?

---

Let's look at a simplified example to clarify my question: If we have a function like `add` and `map` …

```
// add :: Number -> Number -> Number
// map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

If we wanted to define a function using `map` and `add` we could figure out the type *systematically* **without knowing `add` or `map`'s implementation**

```
// add :: Number -> Number -> Number
// map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

// add6 :: Number -> Number
let add6 = add (6) 

// mapAdd6 :: [Number] -> [Number]
let mapAdd6 = map(add6)
```

This is really powerful because it allows you to reason about code you didn't make without having to go digging through the implementation (as much)

However, when trying to do it with the `comp2` example, I get stuck pretty quick

```
// comp :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)

// comp2 :: ??
const comp2 = comp (comp) (comp)

// initial type
(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)

// apply to comp once ... ???
[(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)] -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)

// apply the second time ... ???
[(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)] -> [(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)] -> (a -> c)

// no... this can't be right
```

HOW TO HINDLEY MILNER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s see what we know. Let’s look at `comp2`’s implementation in isolation:

```
comp2 = comp comp comp
```

And let’s consider `comp`’s type signature:

```
comp :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Now, the result of `comp2` is going to be the result of `comp` applied to two arguments, which is the far right hand side of the `comp` type signature. Therefore, we know that the type of `comp2` is of type `a -> c`, we just don’t know what `a` and `c` are yet.

However, we can figure it out. We can work through this by hand by manually *unifying* types (by knowing that two types need to be the same), then *substituting* known type variables with their concrete types. The two arguments are both `comp`, but they should have different types: `b -> c` and `a -> b`, respectively. Let’s add some type annotations to make that a little more clear:

```
comp2 = (comp (comp :: b -> c)
              (comp :: a -> b))
```

We can first attempt to unify `b -> c` with the type of `comp` to determine what `b` and `c` are, but we’ll need to do some alpha-renaming so that our variable names don’t collide:

```
b          -> c
(b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> (a1 -> c1)

b = b1 -> c1
c = (a1 -> b1) -> (a1 -> c1)
```

Next, we can do the same thing with the second argument, unifying with the type `a -> b`:

```
a          -> b
(b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b2) -> (a2 -> c2)

a = b2 -> c2
b = (a2 -> b2) -> (a2 -> c2)
```

But wait! We now have two different definitions for the same type variable, `b`, so those must unify as well. Let’s perform the same process for these two types:

```
b1         -> c1
(a2 -> b2) -> (a2 -> c2)

b1 = a2 -> b2
c1 = a2 -> c2
```

Now, returning to the original type we gave for `comp2`, we can perform a series of substitutions to end up with a complete type:

```
a -> c                                                 | type of comp2, from the return type of comp
(b2 -> c2) -> c                                        | substituting the definition of a
(b2 -> c2) -> (a1 -> b1) -> (a1 -> c1)                 | substituting the definition of c
(b2 -> c2) -> (a1 -> (a2 -> b2)) -> (a1 -> c1)         | substituting the definition of b1
(b2 -> c2) -> (a1 -> (a2 -> b2)) -> (a1 -> (a2 -> c2)) | substituting the definition of c1
(b2 -> c2) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b2) -> a1 -> a2 -> c2       | removing unnecessary parentheses
(c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d               | alpha renaming
```

You will notice that this is the same as your manually-prescribed type.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thank you ^_^